# Expected value of attempts needed to find a "pair" of cards

Tags: pr.probability, recreational-mathematics, expectation

We are given an integer $n \geq 1$ and $2n$ cards, labelled $0$ to $2n-1$. We pick a card with uniform probability, put it back, and continue, until for some $k\in \{0,n-1\}$ the cards
$2k$ and $2k+1$ have been picked up at least once, in any order. Then we stop and count the number of steps. Let us call the expected value of steps needed to complete the game $E_n$.

Do we have $0 < \lim\inf_{n\to\infty} E_n/\log(n) < \infty$?

Comment: I think this is very close to the "birthday problem" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Average_number_of_people_to_get_at_least_one_shared_birthday) and as such your $E_n$ should grow like $\sqrt{n}$, not $\log(n)$.

Comment: It appears that this problem is not trivial, and very similar near-coincidence problems were studied by some prominent probabilists -- thank you kodlu again for the reference to https://statistics.stanford.edu/research/methods-studying-coincidences

Comment: @IosifPinelis: I mean, I would say the birthday problem itself is not trivial. But if your comment is implicitly about "is this question a good fit for MO?" then I would say plenty of math is not trivial, but is standard, and for that reason might not be the best for MO.

Comment: @SamHopkins : I agree that being nontrivial may by itself be not enough for MO. However, it was also said that "very similar near-coincidence problems were studied by some prominent probabilists" (which actually surprised me a bit.) Since similar problems were studied in published research, I think the above post is fine for MO.

Comment: Reminds me of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_(card_game)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\J}{\mathcal J}$More or less straightforward calculations show that
$$E_n=\frac1{(2 n-1)!}\sum _{k=0}^n a_k,$$
where
$$a_k:=a_{n,k}:=k! (2 n-k-1)! 
\binom{2 n-k+1}{k}.$$

This is rather easy to analyze by considering the ratios $a_{k+1}/a_k$, to get
$$E_n\asymp\sqrt n,$$
as suggested in the comment by Sam Hopkins (even though I do not understand why this is very close to the birthday problem).

---

For an illustration, here is the (connected) plot $\{(n,E_n)\colon n=1,\dots,1000\}$:

[image]

---

Thinking a bit more about the comment by Sam Hopkins, now the similarity with the birthday problem seems clearer to me: there, we deal with exact coincidences of birthdays, here with near coincidences of ($2n$)-nomial outcomes.

---

**Details:** We do not have to assume that the number of cards, say $m$, is even. Let then $n:=\lfloor(m+1)/2\rfloor$.

Let $\nu_m$ be the number of steps needed to have picked up, at least for some $k$, the neighbor cards labeled $k$ and $k+1$, so that
\begin{equation*}
    E_m:=E\nu_m=\sum_{r=0}^\infty P(\nu_m>r). \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
Note that
\begin{equation*}
    P(\nu_m>r)=\frac1{m^r}\,\sum_{k\ge0}\,\sum_{J\in\J_{m,k}}S_{k,r}
    =\frac1{m^r}\,\sum_{k\ge0}|\J_{m,k}| \, S_{k,r}, \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    \J_{m,k}:=\Big\{J\subseteq[m]\colon|J|=k,\ \sum_{j=0}^{m-1}1(\{j,j+1\}\subseteq J)=0\Big\},
\end{equation*}
$[m]:=\{1,\dots,m\}$, $|\cdot|$ denotes the cardinality, and $S_{k,r}$ is the number of maps from $[r]$ *onto* $[k]$. By inclusion-exclusion,
\begin{equation*}
    S_{k,r}=\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom kj (k-j)^r,
\end{equation*}
with $0^0:=1$.

The set $\J_{m,k}$ is obviously in a one-to-one correspondence with the set (say $Q_{m,k}$) of all sequences in $\{0,1\}^m$ with exactly $k\,$ $1$'s such that between any two subsequent $1$'s there is at least one $0$.

In turn, the set $Q_{m,k}$ is in a one-to-one correspondence with the set (say $R_{m,k}$) of all sequences in $\{0,1\}^{m-(k-1)}$ with exactly $k\,$ $1$'s: a  bijection from $Q_{m,k}$ onto $R_{m,k}$ can be obtained by removing one $0$ from between any two subsequent $1$'s.

Thus, $|\J_{m,k}|=|Q_{m,k}|=|R_{m,k}|=\binom{m-k+1}k$ and hence, by (1) and (2),
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    E_m
    &=\sum_{k\ge0}\binom{m-k+1}k \, \sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom kj \sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{(k-j)^r}{m^r}  \\
    &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{m-k+1}k \, \sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom kj \frac m{m-k+j}  \\
    &=m\,\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{m-k+1}k \, \sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom kj \int_0^1 dx\,x^{m-k+j-1}  \\
    &=m\,\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{m-k+1}k \, \int_0^1 dx\,x^{m-k-1}(1-x)^k  \\
    &=m\,\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{m-k+1}k \, \frac{k!(m-k-1)!}{m!} \\
    &=\sum_{k=0}^n b_k,
\end{aligned}   
\tag{3}  
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    b_k:=b_{m,k}:=\binom{m-k+1}k\Big/\binom{m-1}k.
\end{equation*}

It is easy to see that $b_k$ is decreasing in $k$, with
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{b_{k+1}}{b_k}=1-(1+o(1))\frac kn=\exp\Big\{-(1+o(1))\frac kn\Big\}
\end{equation*}
if $k=o(n)$. Since $b_0=1$, we have
\begin{equation*}
    b_k=\exp\Big\{-(1+o(1))\frac{k^2}{2n}\Big\}
\end{equation*}
if $k=o(n)$. Also, since $b_k$ is decreasing in $k$, it follows that $b_k=\exp\big\{-c^2 n/3\big\}$ if $k\ge cn$ and $n$ is large enough, for any fixed $c>0$. Thus, by (3),
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    E_m
    &\sim\int_0^n dx\,\exp\Big\{-\frac{x^2}{2n}\,(1+o(1))\Big\}
    \sim\sqrt{\frac\pi2}\, \sqrt n\approx1.25\,\sqrt n; 
\end{aligned}   
\tag{3}  
\end{equation*}
cf. the picture above.

Comment: It's close to the birthday problem because we're trying to count collisions between $2k$ and $2k+1$ (instead of say $k$ and itself), but that should not make a huge difference.

Comment: Whoops I see you just said this.

Comment: @SamHopkins : Thank you for this explanation. This occurred to me just a few moments before I saw this explanation. :-)

Comment: Diaconis and Mosteller studied 'near coincidences'. Cannot get to the paywalled paper but a long report is here (see p. 51 for a relevant approximation) https://statistics.stanford.edu/research/methods-studying-coincidences

Comment: @kodlu : Thank you for this interesting reference. Wow, a number of well-known people studied such matters! The result most closely related to (but not quite the same as) the above one is apparently given by formula (9.5) on p. 54 of that report.

Comment: I have added details of the calculations.